# Get session-time (start and close time) of main chart series in pinescript

Tags: charts, reset, pine-script

I am currently trying to write up a script in Pine Script for TradingView, and am having difficulties getting the session (the start and close times) of the current displayed main chart series.
e.g for Nikkei225, the session would be 8:45am - 5:30am (UTC+9)

I am using this to make a Ku-Chart which resets every day on the close time of the main chart series.
Also having difficulty drawing a vertical line at this close time.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

See the [How To Show Vertical Lines](https://www.tradingview.com/script/7xoz2sEd-How-To-Show-Vertical-Lines/) script by allanster.

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas about the session times?

Comment: The link handles session times, no?

Comment: I don't think so. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but I want to pull the session open and close times automatically from the currently displayed chart. I think your link shows manual settings for these times.

Comment: How will you be using the session open and close times in your script?

Comment: I am running a Ku-Chart script and would like it to reset at the open/close times of the currently displayed chart. Similar to this one: https://www.tradingview.com/script/lOTCl2fI/